# How to clear up the data after I use PlotWidget.plot() in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

My code is:

```
class Ui_Registos2(object):
    def setupUi(self, Registos2, Info):

        self.Grafico_2 =  pg.PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.Grafico_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 430, 501, 331))
        self.Grafico_2.setObjectName("Grafico_2")       

    def openfile(self):
        name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        filename = name[0]

       if len(filename) <=0:
           return
       try:            
           self.Info.file = open(filename, 'r')

       except NameError:          
           return

       self.Info.df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='Tabela', encoding="utf-8")

       i = 0
       items = []

        # TABLE HEADER
       for field in self.Info.df.columns:
           items.append(QtGui.QStandardItem(field))

       self.model.appendRow(items)        
       n = [] # CADA LINHA DA TABELA        
       while i<len(self.Info.df):

           linha2 = self.Info.df.loc[i] 
           n = []
           for item in linha2:
               print(item)
               n.append(QtGui.QStandardItem(str(item))) 

           self.model.appendRow(n) 
           i+=1 
           #FIRST GRAPH              
           self.y =self.Info.df.loc[:,'%']
           self.x =self.Info.df.loc[:,'t']

           pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0))
           self.data_line =  self.Grafico.plot(self.x, self.y, pen=pen)     
           self.plot = self.pw.plot(x, y, pen=None, symbol="o", symbolBrush="r")
```

So every time I clicked the button 'openfile', I want to clean the existed data and replot the new one, but PlotWidget rewrite on the existing graph.
Is there any way to clean the data?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear a plot with plot.clear(). I cannot test your example but this should work:

```
self.Grafico.clear()
self.pw.clear()
```